# Nothing being Outputted after first Function Call - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, active-directory

I'm working on a javascript project that will list everything from user name, email, phone number, and notes from AD into into a spreadsheet, so far i have two functions. however anything i put after getExternalID(users[i].externalIds ||[] does not output any information. here's a snippet of what i have. I'm a bit of a novice, would this be due to how I formatted the script?

```
function writeToSpreadsheet(){
    var values = [];
    var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain:'domain'}).users; 
    for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
      values.push([users[i].name.fullName, getExternalID(users[i].externalIds ||[], getPhones(users[i].phones ||[], ))]); // accounts for blank data 
    }
    
    var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docslink';
    SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}


function getExternalID(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(ExternalIDsObj) {
        return ExternalIDsObj.value;
    }).join(', ') + ('@differentemail')  //takes employeeID and adds Email Address
    
}


function getPhones(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(phoneObj) {
        return phoneObj.value;
    }).join(', ')
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using ````console.log(values)```` to check if the names and emails are correctly pushed into the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are aiming to output the data from Active Directory into a spreadsheet, you need to use Sheets API to do that after populating the `values` array.

Also, for best practice the two get functions are separated from the main function.

**Edit:** There must be a typo on your closing parenthesis on your `getExternalID()` call. It's only supposed to get one argument.

**Sample Code:**

```
function writeToSpreadsheet(){
  var values = [];
  var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({domain:'domain'}).users; 
  for (var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
    values.push([users[i].name.fullName, getExternalID(users[i].externalIds || []), getPhones(users[i].phones || [])]);
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);

}  
    
function getExternalID(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(ExternalIDsObj) {
    return ExternalIDsObj.value;
  }).join(', ') + ('@differentemail.com');
}
        
function getPhones(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(phoneObj) {
    return phoneObj.value;
  }).join(', ');
}
```

**Sample Output:** (note that these "accounts" do not have external ID information in Admin Console)

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that, but i did have that already in the code. it was at the bottom, but i moved it to below the values.push line similar to how you have it inputted. As to answer your first question. the values seem to be coming in fine by themselves. If i move 'getExternalID(users[i].externalIds' behind phones. then the phone value is outputted, but the external id does not.  and vice versa.

Comment: Please edit your equation to include your **complete** code. Also, I edited my answer as well based on the understanding that you wanted ````externalIds.value```` and ````phones.value```` to appear on the spreadsheet. Please let me know if this is sufficient.

Comment: Hmm looks good now, looks the typo with the parenthesis was the cause. Thank you very much

Comment: Much appreciated!